# App hangs for several seconds, how to diagnose what methods are causing it?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

My app is hanging when returning from one activity back to a ListView activity. I know the ListView is slow and RecyclerView is a better replacement, however I don't think this would be causing complete UI freezing for multiple seconds (I see ListView lag however this hang is 100% unresponsiveness). The hanging is almost always persistent until you close and re-open the app, and ANR is almost always triggered.

I have messed around with TraceView and see a lot of Object.wait() calls taking up CPU time, but I don't know how to interpret that. Where can I go from here?

Edit (more info):

There is a lot going on from SQLite, image loading, rest calls and so on going on in the app and I've been running Strict Mode and fixing issues but nothing shows up in Strict Mode logs when this type of hang happens (which is very reproduceable)

[Screenshot of systrace during hang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCaow.png)

Comment: *the ListView is slow and RecyclerView is a better replacement, however I don't think this would be causing* your systrace log disagrees

Comment: What exactly gives you this determination from the log? I am new to reading systrace logs. Would you think this could cause 5+ seconds hanging?

Comment: I see 8 alerts, of which at least 4 are about the inefficient list view

Comment: can you post the listview activity's  `onResume`  method, if you are overriding it on the activity